# jenkinsfile not passing env to sh

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to set environment variable in Jenkinsfile following way,

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'slave1' }

    stages {
        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    BUILD_VERSION = sh (
                        script: 'python get_firmware_version.py',
                        returnStdout: true
                    ).trim()
                }
                echo "${BUILD_VERSION}"
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'image-sign', variable: 'IMAGE_SIGN')]) {
                    dir('firmware/') {
                        echo "${BUILD_VERSION}"
                        sh '''
                           echo "Building"
                           echo "${BUILD_VERSION}"
                           echo "${env.BUILD_VERSION}"
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            script {
                echo "Pipeline Failed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But its failing with following error `Bad substitution`

```
[Pipeline] echo
0_2_0
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo Building
Building
/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/Firmware/Branch/firmware@tmp/durable-54e04481/script.sh: 3: /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/Firmware/Branch/firmware@tmp/durable-54e04481/script.sh: Bad substitution
```

Why I can't set ENV Var and use it in sh step ?

Comment: Inside the shell the syntax to access env vars is $BUILD_VERSION.

Comment: `echo ${BUILD_VERSION}` prints empty in `sh`

Comment: Because that is incorrect syntax in sh. Just use `echo $BUILD_VERSION` in the shell section. The syntax in Jenkinsfile and the syntax in a shell script are different for accessing environment variables.

Comment: `echo $BUILD_VERSION` prints empty in `sh`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is Jenkins thing I think. When you use the `sh` block with `'`; it will not have access to things like environment variables. Try using the `"` instead. That should work

```
sh """
    echo "Building"
    echo "${env.BUILD_VERSION}"
    echo "${env}"
"""
```

Jenkins should recognise the shell block and escape the `"` within the `"""` automatically.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'slave1' }

    stages {
        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    BUILD_VERSION = sh (
                        script: 'python get_firmware_version.py',
                        returnStdout: true
                    ).trim()
                }
                echo "${BUILD_VERSION}"
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'image-sign', variable: 'IMAGE_SIGN')]) {
                    dir('firmware/') {
                        echo "${BUILD_VERSION}"
                        sh """
                           echo "Building"
                           echo "${BUILD_VERSION}"
                           echo "${env.BUILD_VERSION}"
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            script {
                echo "Pipeline Failed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> My test case

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'devops-jenkins-slave'
    }
  }

  options {
    timestamps()
  }

  stages {

    stage('Setup'){
      steps {
        dir("${WORKSPACE}/"){
          script {
            BUILD_VERSION = "1"
          }

          sh """
           echo "${BUILD_VERSION}"
          """
        }
      }
    }

  }

    post {
      always {
        dir("${WORKSPACE}/"){
          deleteDir()
        }
      }
    }
}
```

> Result

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on devops-jenkins-slave in /home/jenkins/workspace/Samples/Test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timestamps
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Setup)
[Pipeline] dir
22:09:55 Running in /home/jenkins/workspace/Samples/Test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] sh
22:09:56 [Test] Running shell script
22:09:56 + echo 1
22:09:56 1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] dir
22:09:56 Running in /home/jenkins/workspace/Samples/Test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: `illegal string character after dollar sign` got for this change

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Try deleting `echo "${env.BUILD_VERSION}"`?

Comment: Do you have a line reff of the offending line?

Comment: Single versus double quotes don't make any difference for me.

Comment: @parsley72 is your scenario similar to the original post?